# Indoor Navigation Application

Tags: navigation, maps, simulation

I have been given a task to create an indoor navigation application (android based). Localisation is not needed. Only use a routing algorithm on a map that would give shortest routes from one point on the map to another. I don't even know where and how to start working on something like this. How to make a map and then link it to the algorithm. How to test my applications through simulations. I can create small android applications but this is way above my expertise however i have to and want to complete this. This would be an excellent learning experience. Any guidance on this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I did this for an Android application. We used an SVG file, and displayed the SVG in an Android WebView component. Check out my answer for details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130244/svg-vector-map-indoor-navigational-routing/42742026#42742026.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help, but I would start looking at some pathfinding guidance.
Take a look at this for example, [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm)

Comment: Should probably be a comment.